# MySql - unique key not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, unique-constraint

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `timeline_lists` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `list_type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `s_object_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `new_items_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_accessed_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_on` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`user_id`),
  KEY `unique_index` (`user_id`,`list_type`,`s_object_id`,`group_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

every time I run the following query a new record is added:

```
INSERT INTO `timeline_lists` (`id`,`user_id`,`list_type`,`s_object_id`,`group_id`,`new_items_count`,`last_accessed_on`,`last_updated_on`,`created_at`,`updated_at`) 
VALUES 
(NULL,18724,11,0,0,5,'2014-09-23 16:37:46',NULL,'2014-09-23 16:37:48','2014-09-23 16:37:48') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`timeline_lists`.`new_items_count`=VALUES(`new_items_count`),
`timeline_lists`.`last_accessed_on`=VALUES(`last_accessed_on`),
`timeline_lists`.`updated_at`=VALUES(`updated_at`)
```

I would expect that the unique index effect and the fields would just get updated instead, if I tun this query 5 times I would get 5 records in the DB instead of just 1.

what am I missing here?

Comment: Have a look at @Vérace comments to my answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `UNIQUE` key on your table, only a `PRIMARY KEY` on an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, which never trigger the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` because, as you probably already know, you're passing `id = NULL`.

Change this:

```
KEY `unique_index` (`user_id`,`list_type`,`s_object_id`,`group_id`)
```

to this:

```
UNIQUE INDEX `unique_index` (`user_id`,`list_type`,`s_object_id`,`group_id`)
```

Comment: +1 - well spotted! Just because you name a KEY/INDEX 'unique_index' doesn't make it UNIQUE. I don't have a  system up and running, but if I named a KEY/INDEX 'primary_key', I'd bet every cent I've ever earned that it wouldn't act like a PRIMARY KEY. :-). One suggestion though, don't forget a NOT NULL constraint just to be safe.

Comment: Just stick a NOT NULL on group_id.

Comment: @Vérace That would be cool: data constraints based on natural language, i.e. `KEY` `all_english_alphabet_letters_except_e_and_k_if_inserting_data_on_monday_and_before_2016`. Just kidding, of course :)

Comment: Add a couple of GB to the MySQL install for a natural language parser - where's the problem? :-)